# Why is IdentityServer redirecting to http rather than https?

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, appharbor

I have a very simple MVC5 website that I'm trying to secure with IdentityServer3.

Both my website and my IdentityServer instance are hosted as separate sites in AppHarbor.  Both are behind https.

When I hit a resource in my website that is protected by an `[Authorize]` attribute (e.g., `/Home/About`), I am successfully redirected to IdentityServer, and I can successfully authenticate.

When IdentityServer POSTs its response back to the website (via `app.FormPostResponse.js`), the website responds with a 302 redirect to the requested resource - as expected.  However, *this redirect is to **http**, not https (see the network trace below*).

I'm sure this is just something wrong with my IdentityServer config, but I'd appreciate any pointers as to what I've got wrong.

(AppHarbor uses a reverse proxy (nginx I believe) in front of IIS, where SSL terminates - so I have `RequireSsl = false` for this scenario, as per the IdentityServer documentation.)

Here is my website's `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://<my-idsrv3>.apphb.com/identity",

            ClientId = "<my-client-id>",
            Scope = "openid profile roles email",
            RedirectUri = "https://<my-website>.apphb.com",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            UseTokenLifetime = false
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Here is Startup.cs from my IdentityServer3 instance:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "My Identity Server",
                SigningCertificate = Certificates.LoadSigningCertificate(),
                RequireSsl = false,
                PublicOrigin = "https://<my-idsrv3>.apphb.com",

                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of my website Client:

```
new Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientName = "My Website Client",
    ClientId = "<my-client-id>",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "https://<my-website>.apphb.com"
    },

    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
}
```

Here is the trace from Chrome, after clicking 'Yes, Allow' on the IdentityServer consent screen:

[image: Chrome network trace]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect URI sent as HTTP and not HTTPS in app running HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468033/redirect-uri-sent-as-http-and-not-https-in-app-running-https)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks like this issue was caused by my client website being behind an SSL-terminating nginx front-end.

With reference to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin/issues/30), I added the following to the start of my website's app configuration:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    string proto = ctx.Request.Headers.Get("X-Forwarded-Proto");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proto))
    {
        ctx.Request.Scheme = proto;
    }
    await next();
});
```

This makes the website aware that incoming requests were over https; this in turn appears to ensure that the IdentityServer3 middleware generates https uri's.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue running identityserver4 in an Azure App Service. Even with forced `https`, the generated urls in `.well-known/openid-configuration` were still `http://`.

Fixed using the same solution as the other answer, but using AspNetCore `ForwardedHeadersExtensions`:

```cs
var forwardOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
    // Needed because of mixing http and https.
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false,
};

// Accept X-Forwarded-* headers from all sources.
forwardOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
forwardOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);
```

See also https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1331 for more discussion on this subject.

Comment: The `.Clear();` part was necessary for this solution to work for me. `RequireHeaderSymmetry` is `false` by default.

Comment: Wasn't easy to find a solution that works, but for anyone coming along here: This worked for me after migrating from IIS on Windows to Linux based Docker containers in Kubernetes. Make sure to add this before you call `app.UseIdentityServer();`.

Answer (score 1):

Add forwarded headers in your startup

```
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost;
    });
```

and

```
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
```

Finally tell the config it has to replace the http to https in the redirect url. I'm still looking for a  better way to implement this.

in your .addopenidconnect() add:

```
 Func<RedirectContext, Task> redirectToIdentityProvider = (ctx) =>
                     {
                         if (!ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.StartsWith("https") && !ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Contains("localhost"))
                             ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http", "https");
                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     };
                     opt.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                     {
                         OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = redirectToIdentityProvider
                     };
```