# Redirect URI sent as HTTP and not HTTPS in app running HTTPS

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have an Asp .net core MVC app.  Which connects to an Identity Server 4 for authentication.   Hosted in a docker swarm

MVC app is hosted on https://XXXXXXX

ConfigurServies

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
             .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                //options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));
                // when the identity has been created from the data we receive,
                // persist it with this authentication scheme, hence in a cookie
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // Identity server endpoint
                options.Authority = settingsSetup.IdentityServerEndpoint;

                // Client id to login with
                options.ClientId = settingsSetup.ClientId;
                // Client secret.
                options.ClientSecret = settingsSetup.Secret;

                // Scope of our API
                options.Scope.Add("testapi");
                options.Scope.Add("devconsole");
                // adding offline_access to get a refresh token
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });
```

When I try to run the app I get a redirect uri miss match error.

```
Invalid redirect_uri: http://developerconsole.XXXXX.io/signin-oidc
{
  "ClientId": "BB1D2DA8-D7E4-4AF5-94FA-19EAD6B7D711.apps.XXXXX.biz",
  "ClientName": "Developer Console",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:55000/signin-oidc",
    "http://localhost:55000/auth.html",
    "http://localhost:55000/auth-silent.html"
    "https://developerconsole.XXXXX.io/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "21379983",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "BB1D2DA8-D7E4-4AF5-94FA-19EAD6B7D711.apps.XXXXX.biz",
    "redirect_uri": "http://developerconsole.XXXXX.io/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile testapi devconsole offline_access",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "636625889658410682.MjNlMmQwNjgtZmY0MC00MmVkLWFiNmMtN2M2YmQ5YTM5ZTQ3NjFiYzI2ZjktZWM0Yi00NDk3LTk1ZWMtNjJkYjViMDYwMTJm",
    "state": "CfDJ8Pwa8A3ipXlKtuyxNMpMxAz5QUFmdSunRKdlKS9sS390AKp8gIUZShQUMMCkFAhYLytitgsXUBgwlQDJaJvtHFqzHygLCPwS8Jab6IJzhpry90qS51E1y_eRlppamRDOzYDZ6fcDFzWV1U43BTP2B6pnPTSLNcZRaooyGBXtNokeUqOJ--u-_MOQB8Bw3n2cRyV4kisHNkslD1Gsi2wn1Cx6aTVlqzw_pxHelAXm1P8FyDJpD7G0azFgKgpQF0DRJtC5penRJQzHIHvQN8v4ECGeuSD1zlyfJYClLO2r6kY_R2OYqtBkV0r_SNc9h7xUYmnVaHKQzYqVc_mJO4iLLSMTZrBUICZWR8c4PZw0Os3N",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
    "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
  }
}
```

The error is coming because i have         `"https://developerconsole.XXXXX.io/signin-oidc"` as a redirect uri and not         `"http://developerconsole.XXXXX.io/signin-oidc"`   I dont want to add HTTP redirect uris.

Why is my app building the redirect uri has http and not https?

If i do add the HTTP on i am getting an annoying Correlation  error.  which i think is due to the fact that its being returned by the server as https since the server automatically converts http to https.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Correlation failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Exception: Correlation failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

I probably dont need to mention this works fine on localhost :/

Comment: Could this be because you are behind a (L7) load balancer and internal communication behind the balancer happens in HTTP, not HTTPS?

Comment: Well i know we have a load balancer and i know who to go bug.

Comment: ...in which case, the Forwarded Headers Middleware in [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/) might help. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Only if necessary, talk to the load-balancer admin to ensure that `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers are included in forwarded requests. The probably are.

Comment: I was just told (l4) the one in the docker swarm.    This works in a different project @spender wondering if he has added it to that project and not this one.

Comment: If it's layer4 load-balancing, then the above is not applicable.

Comment: Can you double check to make sure `settingsSetup.IdentityServerEndpoint` is correct?

Comment: @penleychan if it wasn't right i wouldn't be getting the correct response back from the Identity server.   The server is logging me in its my App that is not invaliding the login correctly

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.   By setting UseForwardedHeaders it now sends all the requests as HTTPS.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```

> Correlation failed.

is now fixed and i no longer need to have a http and https redirect uris.

Comment: In case the app is being deployed on Linux (say .NET core app on a linux docker container), in addition to setting the Forward headers also had to clear out the `KnownNetworks` and `KnownProxies` for making sure the redirect url remained https. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies for more details.

Comment: @SuketuBhuta That bit of info was really useful

Comment: We had to use this solution because, we redirected HTTP to HTTPS in the NGINX conf behind an aws ELB. and it worked like charm for us.

Comment: @SuketuBhuta how/where/when did you clear out the `KnownNetworks` and `KnownProxies`?

Comment: @David, see this section of the article I've linked above : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1, basically you clear after setting the `ForwardingHeader`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to add both .addForwardedheaders and .useforwardedheaders().
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68757575/7064454

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET Core 6 added an [easier way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies) to accomplish this for non-IIS scenarios where TLS is terminated before reaching the deployed web application:

> To forward the scheme from the proxy in non-IIS scenarios, enable the
> Forwarded Headers Middleware by setting [the environment variable]
> `ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` to `true`.

Setting this variable fixed the issue for my Docker application running in an Azure container app, without needing to make any changes to Program.cs.

Comment: This workaround worked for me in a .NET 6.0 Docker container running in AWS ECS environment.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18, Nginx, .NetCore 3.1 it works like:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
            });
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` or your web config file

```
location / {

# under your configuration
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Then it started to redirect to https, and without nginx config i got error 503.

Comment: have you tested with .net 6?

Comment: no i didn't updated project yet. When i will, i will also edit this response

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET core documentation says if the forwarded headers are not working add this middleware

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next(context);
});
```

Refer to the Scenarios and User cases section of - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Please note this VERY IMPORTANT DETAIL: the scenario is for **"When it isn't possible to add forwarded headers and all requests are secure"**. I had an IdentityServer4 service hosted in a k8s cluster that received both secure request from the outside and non-secure requests from inside the cluster, and this hack middleware caused my discovery documents to always contain HTTPS URLs, which was a problem for internal requests. **DO NOT USE THIS if you plan to host IdentityServer4 in a Kubernetes cluster** - other applications may suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamil was the key to solve my problem.
More or less the same configuration (Ubuntu 16.04, Net Core 3.1 and nGinx). This setup was needed to make Google authentication to work even on my online website (locally everything worked fine) without the *redirect_uri_mismatch* issue.

In Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices I have:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => {});
```

In Startup.cs -> Configure:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false,
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All,
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

In the server, file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
     ...
     ssl on;
     ...
     location / {
          proxy_pass http://dotnet;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     }
     ...
}
```

In file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
    ...
    # Solution to get always HTTPS
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

only add this code to your web.config file and of course change.com with your website , anyone enter the URL in the browser direct Redirect URI from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="IP Hit" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://www.exemple.com" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.exemple.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
 <system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer only moves the destination from http to https, it doesn't make links render in https.